# Saving image after using requests/sessions

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I'm very confused on how to save my image after 'getting' it using requests/sessions! Please note that `url`, `img_name`, and `img_end` are all defined above, they take a static URL and add numbers to the end to request images corresponding to those numbers.

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('username', 'password')
s.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})
s.get(url+img_name+img_end, headers={'x-test2': 'true'})
```

If I do `print(s)` I get `<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x036A3710>` which leads to think that my image is downloading. However if I do something like `save_img = Image.open(s)` I get a response that `Session has no attribute read`. If anyone can explain how to save the image that I requested to a file that would be amazing, I'm new to Python and this part isn't making sense. Also if my code above is wrong I basically copied the examples from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/ for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

`<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x036A3710>` is the *session object* itself in memory, and has nothing to do with the image, so don't let that confuse you (any instance of a Python object has an address in memory).

The `get` function will *return* the data you want, so you have to store it using a variable:

```
data = s.get(url+img_name+img_end, headers={'x-test2': 'true'})
with open('image', 'wb') as fobj:
    fobj.write(data.content)
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work, however, why does the file that I output seem to be corrupt and/or contain no real data? I can't open the image, but it is 370kb so there is something?

Comment: Are you saving it with the correct file extension, e.g. `open('image.jpg', 'wb')`?

Comment: yes, I've tried .jpg  and .png, both formats I get an output that is 370KB but there is not an image